# How to edit Advanced Search Form's Content Type checkbox-list using hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, search

I have a Drupal 7 setup. I want to remove few Content types from the Content Type checklist that appears in Advanced Search form. I could see that advanced search form comes in 'advanced' field-set of 'search_form'.

I tried to implement the solution given [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2009-02-25/how-to-modify-the-advanced-search-form#comment-2013546), but I am not able to find the advanced array in $form.

I would also like to add styling changes and prefix elements to default text-fields that comes within Advanced Search form
[image: Advanced Search form fields]

Please find the below code that displays content of $form ($form_id = search_form), as I can't find advanced array within it.

```
    Array
(
    [#action] => /demodrupal7/search/node
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => search-form
                )

        )

    [module] => Array
        (
            [#type] => value
            [#value] => node
        )

    [basic] => Array
        (
            [#type] => container
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => container-inline
                        )

                )

            [keys] => Array
                (
                    [#type] => textfield
                    [#title] => Enter your keywords
                    [#default_value] => 
                    [#size] => 40
                    [#maxlength] => 255
                )

            [processed_keys] => Array
                (
                    [#type] => value
                    [#value] => 
                )

            [submit] => Array
                (
                    [#type] => submit
                    [#value] => Search
                )

        )

    [#form_id] => search_form
    [#type] => form
    [#build_id] => form-wAV_M_UAj5lbJgb-6vcdpmtxls5NpioPam6uNtkzRnw
    [form_build_id] => Array
        (
            [#type] => hidden
            [#value] => form-wAV_M_UAj5lbJgb-6vcdpmtxls5NpioPam6uNtkzRnw
            [#id] => form-wAV_M_UAj5lbJgb-6vcdpmtxls5NpioPam6uNtkzRnw
            [#name] => form_build_id
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_build_id
                )

        )

    [#token] => search_form
    [form_token] => Array
        (
            [#id] => edit-search-form-form-token
            [#type] => token
            [#default_value] => 374_q2sHn_uhIvUhwOdrriFMIM3UgfVoc7Jzsh_DHrE
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_token
                )

        )

    [form_id] => Array
        (
            [#type] => hidden
            [#value] => search_form
            [#id] => edit-search-form
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_id
                )

        )

    [#id] => search-form
    [#method] => post
    [#theme_wrappers] => Array
        (
            [0] => form
        )

    [#icon] => 
    [#icon_position] => before
    [#process] => Array
        (
            [0] => bootstrap_form_process
        )

    [#pre_render] => Array
        (
            [0] => bootstrap_pre_render
        )

    [#tree] => 
    [#parents] => Array
        (
        )

    [#validate] => Array
        (
            [0] => search_form_validate
        )

    [#submit] => Array
        (
            [0] => search_form_submit
        )

    [#theme] => Array
        (
            [0] => search_form
        )

)
```

Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advanced fields are added by the node.module in [`node_form_search_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_form_search_form_alter/7.x) (a [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) implementation). It sounds like your module's `hook_form_alter()` is getting called before the node.module one, so you're not seeing it's additions.

The ordering of when hooks are fired is controlled by the `weight` column in the system table. Have you altered that previously for your module? Usually, node.module has a weight of 0 so if your module comes before that in the rows in the system table when sorted by weight then that will be your problem.

Comment: Good catch! As for the hook execution order, if two modules have the same weight, the alphabetical order is used. If mynode.module has weight 0 too, its hooks are executed before the hooks from node.module. (That point should be made clearer to the OP.)

Comment: The order can be changed via [`hook_module_implements_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x). The target hook would be `form_alter` then.

Comment: Thanks @Leigh. Increasing weight of custom module worked for me.

Comment: Both modules (node.module and custom_tasks.module) were having same weight as zero and as @kiamlaluno stated due to alphabetical ordering custom_tasks.module was getting executed before node.module. Once I increased the weight of custom_tasks.module in system table, my hook_form_alter got executed and expected output was achieved. Thanks again.